# Adding dynamic library to my framework give me warnings

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to create a static framework for some reusable code that I would like to include in other iPhone apps. I create this framework by create a bundle .I have added the twitter library to this framework .The problem is that the twitter library import `<libxml/xmlreader.h>` which requires libxml2.dylib so I have added libxml2.dylib to "Link Binary With Libraries" of my bundle but the compiler gives me warnings and the code could not be compiled . I got these warning messages .

```
Unexpected dylib (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//Foundation.framework/Foundation) on link line
Unexpected dylib (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation) on link line
Unexpected dylib (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics) on link line
Unexpected dylib (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//MessageUI.framework/MessageUI) on link line
Unexpected dylib (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//UIKit.framework/UIKit) on link line
Unexpected dylib (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib) on link line
```

Comment: What happens if you try to remove dynamic library from your framework and add it only on final target?

Answer (score 3):

I just fought through this and figured it out. Adding standard frameworks such as CoreFoundation.Framework to a custom framework gets you no where. Those warning will disappear once you remove them from your custom framework. The end user will then have to add the required standard frameworks to their app when implementing your custom framework.

Comment: If you want to help the user remember to link some frameworks you can choose the approach to add the following lines in your Framework header file (although not all developers like it):

    `#ifndef __CFNETWORK__
    #pragma message("CFNetwork framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. Be sure to include all required frameworks.")
    #endif`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add these frameworks to your project either:

> Project target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Add those frameworks one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to eliminate those warnings, maybe you can try this:

> Project target -> Build Settings -> Link With Standard Libraries -> NO

Answer (score 0):

I sove this problem by this step

```
Project target -> Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only (Debug) -> NO
```